# Syntax error on token "try" please delete this token

Tags: java, syntax

So I was trying to read a file, this is my piece of code;

```
try{
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("mikuname.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String str;
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(str + "\n");
        }

        br.close();
    }
```

But when compiling I get an error saying "Syntax error on token "try" please delete this token"

Any idea how I can fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: did you implement a catch block?

Comment: I think you have not included the catch block

Comment: I would usually expect a different error but you have a try without a catch. Try without a catch (or a finally) makes no sense as try is to define a region within which exceptions are dealt with

Comment: @RichardTingle We're missing context of the `try` block. For example: `class X { try { ...OP's stuff...} }` will give this precise error.

Comment: @Marko that would explain the odd error

Comment: Why did you add the `try{` in the first place, why did you decide to put that in your code? You may just do what the compiler suggested: delete the `try` token and see what happens. If you added it for the reason of catching an exception then, as other people suggested, you should do exactly that.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Eclipse definitely complained about the exception.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik That depends on the context, which is not given. If he does what the compiler suggests, then there will be another error with another suggestion. In this case Eclipse will suggest a quick fix - either to add a try/catch or to add a 'throws' declaration to the method. If the OP had just followed the compiler's suggestion he would have probably solved the problem by himself.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt It is quite clear from the error that OP has written that as a direct syntactical child of the class. He just had `{ ... stuff }`; Eclipse complained about the excption, so he added `try` in front; now Eclipse say "no, remove that try". I understand a beginner's confusion there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try always come with atleast one catch block

```
try{
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("mikuname.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String str;
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(str + "\n");
        }

        br.close();
}catch (Exception e){
//some exception information
}
```

check doc for more information about try..catch [link] http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html

Comment: No, `try` [can stand alone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) as of Java 7 (or could have `finally` rather than `catch`).

Answer (score 3):

You have inserted your `try` block *out of the blue* into a class. You may be coming from a scripting language background, where it is always legal to just write standalone action code. In Java such code must find itself either within a *method* or within an *initializer*. If you just want to run some code, then put it into the `main` method:

```
public class MyGuy {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      ... your try-block here ...
  }
}
```

Note that your case is a perfect match for Java 7's *try with resources*:

```
try (FileReader fr = new FileReader("mikuname.txt");
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) 
{
   ... your actions ...
}
```

Comment: Given the text of the error, I suspect you're right.

Comment: I have also tried it to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the `try` block must be accompanied by atleast one `catch` block or a `finally` block.

eg

```
try {
} catch(SomeException e){
} finally {
}
```

Comment: No, `try` [can stand alone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) as of Java 7.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Not just any old `try` :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Sure, but "A `try` block **must** be accompanied by at least one `catch` block or a `finally` block" is no longer true. :-)

Answer (score 1):

***"Any idea how I can fix this?"***

put `catch` block after `try` block. this would be one of the right solution:

```
    catch(Exception e){}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should have a catch block corresponding to try block as follows:

```
try {
...
catch(<exception>) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Java 1.7+, move the declaration of your reader into the resource block:

```
try (FileReader fr = new FileReader("mikuname.txt");) {
    // rest of block same as yours
}
```

catch and/or finally block is not necessary when using resources.

Comment: try with resource available in java7 and higher.We do not know which version OP is using

Comment: @JqueryLearner fair point. Added qualifier.

Comment: Try with resource answer was 1st suggested by you but till now no votes.+1 from my side

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to use the new [`try` with resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) in Java 7. To do that, you use `()` around your resources:

```
try (
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("mikuname.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
) {
    String str;
    while ((str = br.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(str + "\n");
    }

    // You don't need this, it's done by the try: br.close();
}
```

...and of course, you have to make sure you're using Java 7, and you have to use it in a proper context (within a method or within either an instance or static initializer).

Answer (score 0):

As the compiler suggested, you should remove the `try` keyword.
But if you actually intended to catch the IOException that could be thrown, you should add a `catch` clause rather than delete the `try` keyword.

If you're using Java 7, you can clean up your code a bit more. Right now, if there is an error while you read the file, you don't close the file and your application may run out of file descriptors. In Java 7 the try-with-resources statement has a nice way of handling this:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("mikuname.txt"))) {
    String str;
    while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(str + "\n");
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Do something with the IO problem that occurred while reading the file
}
```